# Use CSS flexbox to create a menu with 2 columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a menu similar to that in the image.  I have got most of this working but I'm trying to replicate the container in red.  Only the Items in the red container and with the white font color i.e. More Categories and Learning Guides is not required.

[image]

Im trying to learn flexbox and use display: flex.  The requirements are that it will always have 2 columns.  Ideally it populates the 1st column first and then the second column last i.e. In the image provided the markup would be:

```
<ul>
   <li>Adobe Photoshop</li>
   <li>Adobe Illustrator</li>
   <li>Inspiration</li>
   ...
   <li>News</li>
</ul>
```

Also ideally it would be smart enough to know if there are 6 items then it needs to display 2 columns with 3 rows.  i.e. I wouldnt need to supply a height?

Not sure if this is possible but any help appreciated.

Comment: So you already have the white part of the menu, and are just asking how to build the red menu with two columns?

Comment: Check `flex-wrap`: make a container for menu items (but `More Categories...` and the other), then make every item of `width: 50%;` (basically every value between `34` and `50` would work, whichever makes it look more closely).

Comment: @ObsidianAge that is correct

Comment: @zerkms I have checked it out but I can only get it to populate horizontally.  Not down the columns...Sorry I'll change the OP that the "More Categories" is not required...

Comment: if you want "columns" i can't see why you wouldn't just go with `columns` https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp

Comment: @A.Lau thanks for this.  This worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comment: you need to use the `flex-wrap: wrap` and then set `width` of the elements to the value between `34%` and `50%` whichever works better.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
</div>
```

Vertical one can also be implemented if the height of the container is fixed:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 60px;
}

.item {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
  <div class="item">D</div>
  <div class="item">E</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Zerkms...I had figured this part out already but I would like it to populate the columns vertically rather than horizontally.  I realise this might not be possible with pure css but thought I would ask?

Comment: @GlenHong you can do that if the height of the menu container is fixed (see the updated answer)

Comment: Sorry I had to unmark it as correct...I do have a fixed height for the overall container but your answer needs to know how many items are in it and set the height to the number of items.   Each parent menu has a different set of sub items so I dont want to have to set a fixed height as this will be CMS and likely to change.

Comment: @GlenHong I really like (actually not) how nothing of those crucial details was put in the original question

Comment: they were in the last paragraph.  Not about it being CMS but that I didnt want to put a fixed height on it